# (discord.js) add role to author

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am looking for help, my code handles a "message" event, and I am trying to make it add a role to the author of the comment

My current attempt is

`client.on('message', msg => {msg.member.addRole("[role id]").catch(function(){});})`

however, it does not seem to be working for the various attempts I have made. Any help on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the brackets there to just indicate that's where the role's id would go, or do you also keep them there?

Comment: My problem has been fixed by using: msg.guild.members.get(msg.author.id) to select the user

Answer (score 2):

Use this code. 
Fist check if user don`t have this role, then give him this role

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (!msg.member.roles.some(role => role.id === 'YourROLEID')) {
            msg.member.addRole('YourROLEID')
            .then(console.log(`Succesfuly added role to member ${msg.author.tag}`))
            .catch(console.error)
    }
})
```

Comment: You can just ensure the existence of `msg.member.roles.get('YOUR ID')` instead if you're going to search by ID in the predicate function for `Collection.some()`.

Comment: Hmm, yea, thats right way too. use Get its more correctrly.
`if (!msg.member.roles.some(role => role.id === 'YourROLEID')) {`
can be replaced with 
`if (!msg.member.roles.get('YourROLEID') {`